# SQL Server stored procedure: how to find entries which contain at least the same data in another table, as the input

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have no idea how to title this so sorry if the title makes no sense. I'm really stumped at this exercise, this is part of the database schema:

- Bars (BarID, Name)
- Drinks (DrinkID, Name, TypeID)
- Sells (BarID, DrinkID, Price)

My problem is I need to write a procedure which selects ALL bars that contain at least the same drinks as the bar inputted in the procedure with a variable (e.g. `@barname`).

For example if bar A sells whiskey and coke I need to select all bars that sell at least whiskey and coke.

This is my very over complicated attempt at it with a cursor but I have no idea if I even have to use a cursor with it tbh. I'm really lost.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE similar 
    (@barname AS VARCHAR(30))
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    DECLARE @db AS INT

    SELECT @db = COUNT(*)
    FROM Sells
    WHERE BarID = (SELECT BarID FROM Bars WHERE Bars.Name = @barname)

    SELECT BarID INTO #BarMinDb
    FROM Sells
    WHERE BarID != (SELECT BarID FROM Bars WHERE Bars.Name = @barname)
    GROUP BY BarID
    HAVING COUNT(DrinkID) >= @db

    DECLARE @rn AS INT

    DECLARE kurzor CURSOR FOR 
         SELECT BarID FROM #barMinDb

    OPEN kurzor

    FETCH NEXT FROM kurzor INTO @rn

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
        IF (SELECT DrinkID
            FROM Sells
            WHERE BarID = @rn) IN (SELECT DrinkID 
                                   FROM Sells
                                   WHERE BarID = (SELECT Name FROM Bars 
                                                  WHERE Bars.Name = @barname)
            )
        BEGIN
            PRINT @rn
        END

        FETCH NEXT FROM kurzor INTO @rn

    CLOSE kurzor
    DEALLOCATE kurzor
END
```

Also it is asked of me to select them so I guess I need to use a SELECT and not print them manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This what I have so far.

```
DECLARE @DrinksCount AS INT, @barname AS VARCHAR(30)

set @barname = "QBar";

    -- All drinks of bar @barname
select @DrinksCount = count(s.DrinkID)  from Bars b 
inner join Sells s on b.BarID = s.BarID 
where b.name = @barname

-- All bars offering at least the same drinks
select b.name, count(s.DrinkID) from Bars b 
inner join Sells s on b.BarID = s.BarIDv
inner join
(
-- All drinks of bar @barname
select s.DrinkID  from Bars b 
inner join Sells s on b.BarID = s.BarID 
where b.name = @barname
) a 
on a.DrinkID  = s.DrinkID
having count() = @DrinksCount
group by b.name
```

Comment: This worked, I just had to switch up the last 2 rows (group by before having) but thanks!